# How do I use file contents as arguments in crontab

Tags: cron

I have a file ("IPcontainer") that contains a singular IP-address and I want to use it like so:

```
6tunnel 80 $(< IPcontainer) 80
```

Unfortunately this only works when I do it by hand as opposed to when I use it as a cronjob like so:

```
0 * * * * 6tunnel 80 $(< /home/<MYUSERNAME>/IPcontainer) 80
```

As far as I know cron relies on absolute paths.

How do I need to change it in order for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `cron` uses `/bin/sh` by default - which doesn't support the `$(< file)` syntax

You can either replace

```
$(< /home/<MYUSERNAME>/IPcontainer)
```

by the POSIX

```
$(cat /home/<MYUSERNAME>/IPcontainer)
```

or tell `cron` to use bash explicitly

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
0 * * * * 6tunnel 80 $(< /home/<MYUSERNAME>/IPcontainer) 80
```

See also

- [Understanding Bash's Read-a-File Command Substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189749/understanding-bashs-read-a-file-command-substitution)